# OpenOffice dynamically resized texbox

Tags: pdf, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer

I am creating template of PDF file that consists of key-value data. 
This data is inserted via Java-application. I am creating this template using OpenOffice. There are textbox elements located in table cells. Looks like this:
[image]
 I faced problem with data, that has multiple rows

There is a problem with multiline text. If there is not enough space for additional rows in the textbox, this text disappears and not shown at all. Is it possible to make texbox dynamically resized?

Comment: Regular PDFs (in contrast to PDFs serving as a vehicle for XFA forms) do not know dynamically resized fields.

Comment: Instead of a Text Box, use a Frame anchored `As Character`.